# jQuery Waypoints failing for waypoints on different pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

When I was using an older version of jQuery Waypoints, I was declaring all my waypoints throughout my site in one scripts file, and it didn't matter if an element didn't exist on certain page, that waypoint would either fire or be ignored. However, after updating to the current version, when I have a couple waypoints declared like this:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
  element: $('.stickynav')[0],
  offset: 100,
});

var successStories = new Waypoint({
  element: $('#slider-wrap'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if(direction === 'down'){
      $('ul.navbar-nav li.how').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.navbar-nav li #slider-wrap').addClass('active');
    } else if (direction === 'up'){
      $('ul.navbar-nav li #slider-wrap').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.navbar-nav li.how').addClass('active');
    }
  },
  offset: 90 
});
```

If one of those waypoint elements doesn't exist on the current page I am on, it throws an error that the element isn't being passed in and kills all the processes after that code. Do you have to declare the waypoints on each specific page now?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. I simply wrapped the the function in

```
if($('.selector').length) {
   ...
}
```

To check if the element exists first.